# Do Amazon EBS snapshots retain deleted data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs, undelete

Consider the following scenario:

I have a file with sensitive information stored on an EBS-backed EC2 instance. I delete this file in the standard non-secure way (`rm -f my_secret_file`). Once the file is deleted, I immediately shut down the instance and take an EBS snapshot. (Or create an AMI... either one, really.)

If a malicious party was able to gain access to the snapshot and mount/boot it, could they undelete any portion of `my_secret_file` using the various filesystem tools available? Put another way, do the EBS snapshots retain the data that existed in "unallocated"/deleted blocks at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - I would be extremely surprised if they didn't. The EBS snapshots are block-level snapshots so they will capture everything, regardless of the logical state of the file system similar to a hard disk image.

Comment: So that would mean that using `shred` instead would be a justifiable idea... unless the filesystem was ext4 journaled... ugh.

Comment: Correct. EBS snapshots are not aware of the filesystem or whether there even *is* a filesystem... they're block device snapshots.  http://alestic.com/2009/09/ec2-public-ebs-danger ... using `shred --zero` should shrink the net size of the snapshot (for cost purposes) since EBS does appear to optimize away zero-filled blocks as "empty."